# Guards (If-Else) Inside Lambda Function in Haskell

Tags: if-statement, haskell, lambda, scheme

I wanted to write a function that removes minimum value from an array in Haskell. One of the solutions that I developed in Scheme was

```lisp
(define removemin-cps
  (lambda (lis return)
    (cond
      [(null? lis) (return ('null '()))]
      [(null? (cdr lis)) (return (car lis) '())]
      [else (removemin-cps (cdr lis) (lambda (v1 v2)
                                      (if (< v1 (car lis))
                                          (return v1 (cons (car lis) v2))
                                          (return (car lis) (cons v1 v2)))))])))

(define removemin
  (lambda (lis)
    (removemin-cps lis (lambda (v1 v2)  v2))))
```

I wanted to try something similar in Haskell and ran into the problem that I cannot use either guards or if-else statements inside lambda. Here is what I have:

```hs
removemin_cps [] return = return null []
removemin_cps [h] return = return h []
removemin_cps (h:t) return = removemin_cps t (\v1 v2 ->
                                                | v1 < h       -> return v1 (h:v2)
                                                | otherwise    -> return h (v1:v2))
```

Can I use guards or if-else statements inside lambda or should I come up with another solution to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What went wrong with if-else? Should work fine.

Comment: When I use if-else inside \v1 v2 I get a compiling error that possibly has something to do with type checking but i don't see where confusion with types could have been.. 
• Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Ord (t a -> Bool) (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this) 
• When checking the inferred type removemin_cps :: forall (t :: * -> *) a p. (Foldable t, Ord (t a -> Bool)) => [t a -> Bool] -> ((t a -> Bool) -> [t a -> Bool] -> p) -> p

Comment: It's not a problem of conditionals or guards – it's a type problem. `null` is a function, `Foldable t => t a -> Bool`. `'null` in Scheme is a symbol. I would reach for `Maybe`.

Comment: There is a lot of use of `return`, which is a Haskell keyword. What's the thinking behind this?

Comment: @FrancisKing It's not a keyword.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yes, it is. Monads bind `>>=` and `return`. Hence `return` has been automatically coloured blue in the listing above.

Comment: In short, `v1:v2` says that `v1` has the same type as `v2`'s elements, and passing `null` to `return` makes that type the same as that of `null`. The `Ord` restriction comes from `v1 < h`.

Comment: @FrancisKing No, it's not a keyword. It's an identifier name, and `Monad`'s `return` is being shadowed in the code shown above.

Comment: @FrancisKing There's no "keyword" syntactic category in the Haskell report. The closest you get is "reserved identifier", which is used synonymously with "keyword", and `return` is not one of them – it's just a regular identifier that can be used like any other identifier. For instance, as the name of a function parameter.

Comment: @FrancisKing For whatever reason, the highlighter thought the Haskell code was *Kotlin* (but I have fixed it). That's why `return` was highlighted. `return` is not a keyword in Haskell; it is merely the name of a standard library function (which can be shadowed like any other name). And @OP, I would strongly recommend using a function defined in a `where` instead of writing it inline, just on the basis of readability.

Comment: `k`, IIRC, is the conventional name for the continuation parameter.

Answer (score 2):

So, instead of null I used Nothing and it fixed the problem with the code not compiling but now I'm just very confused about the types. How do I change the type structure so this works? I'm very new to Haskell and its been a nightmare so far...

```
removemin_cps :: (Ord a) => [Maybe a] -> (Maybe a -> [Maybe a] -> p) -> p
removemin_cps [] return = return Nothing []
removemin_cps [h] return = return h []
removemin_cps (h:t) return = removemin_cps t (\v1 v2 -> 
                                                if v1 < h
                                                    then        
                                                         return v1 (h:v2)
                                                    else
                                                         return h (v1:v2))
```

This is what I get when I call the function:

```
*Main> removemin_cps [3 2 0 1] (\v1 v2 -> v2)

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Num (t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> Maybe a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a t1 t2 t3.
              (Ord a, Num t1, Num t2, Num t3, Num (t1 -> t2 -> t3 -> Maybe a)) =>
              [Maybe a]
*Main>
```

Comment: Always write the type before the code. Then the error messages will tell you what the code should be. The correct type is `removemin_cps :: Ord a => [a] -> (Maybe a -> [a] -> r) -> r`. Also, please edit your question with new information instead of self-answering (unless you have an answer!).

Comment: You need commas between list elements: `[3, 2, 0, 1]`. `[3 2 0 1]` is parsed as `[ (((3 2) 0) 1) ]`, that is, a list of one element, which is a call of the number `3` as a function with three arguments. It’s like writing `(removemin-cps (3 2 0 1) k)` instead of `(removemin-cps '(3 2 0 1) k)` in Scheme. Although this wasn’t what you wanted, the error message says that *if* you want it, then there’s a language flag to allow it.